# Why does `Enumerable` have `first` but not `last`?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

`Enumerable` has `first`:

```
(3..5).to_enum.first
# => 3
```

but it does not have `last`:

```
(3..5).to_enum.last
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<Enumerator: 3..5:each>
```

Why is that?

Comment: You would have to fully enumerate and reverse, maybe they wanted the overhead to be more obvious (incase people wondered why first was so fast while the theoretical last seemed to take a while)

Comment: @bjhaid `Enumerable` doesn't have `last` either

Comment: @VictorMoroz the question is referring to `Kernel#to_enum` which generates an `Enumerator` and not an `Enumerable`

Comment: @bjhaid Question is ambiguous but first line says `Enumerable`

Comment: @VictorMoroz The question is not ambiguous. The created object is an `Enumerator`, which does not have `first` but inherits it from `Enumerable`.

Comment: [Post from September 2010 covering this issue](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/217071).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is because not all enumerable objects have the last element.

The simplest example would be:

```
[1, 2, 3].cycle

# (an example of what cycle does)
[1,2,3].cycle.first(9) #=> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Even if the enumerator elements are finite, there is no easy way to get the last element other than iterating through it to the end, which would be extremely inefficient.

Comment: Doesn't explain why `Enumerable` defines e.g. `map` or `max`, won't work with `[1].cycle` too. Why `last` is special?

Comment: @VictorMoroz - It is special as it would work in most of the cases, but it would be inefficient and in some cases might actually break the enumerator (For example iterating through IO objects). It seems like ruby creators thought about adding this method, however decided that it would be broadly misused.

Comment: Simplest example is actually `loop`.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a great reason. Infinite elements break many popular `Enumeable` methods, like `#to_a`, `#min`, `#all?`, and `#reduce`.

Answer (score 6):

Because not all `Enumerable` has last element, and this may or may not because that the `Enumerable` contains no element.

Consider the following `Enumerable`:

```
a = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
  while true
    yielder << 1
  end
end
```

It's a infinite `Enumerable`.

`Enumerable` is a mechanism to iterate a sequence of elements. For some of the iterate process, this may only perform once. In order to get the last element (if there is actually one), it must evaluate the whole iterate process and get the last one. After that, the `Enumerable` is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I can think of is `Enumerable`s may be infinite streams.

```
infinity = Float::INFINITY
range = 1..infinity

range.to_enum.first
# => 1

range.to_a.last # will never finish
```

Comment: I don't think this is the reason because `Float::INFINITY` can appear as the beginning element, in which case `first` would raise an error rather than being undefined: `(Float::INFINITY..5).to_enum
=> #<Enumerator: Infinity..5:each>`. But `(Float::INFINITY..5).to_enum.first # => TypeError: can't iterate from Float`.

Comment: @sawa, that's a problem with the range I used to illustrate my point, not with the concept of infinite streams.

Answer (score -1):

I do not agree with opinion that not all `Enumerable`  has last element. I think few `Enumerator` methods are unable to end the `loop` while responding to `to_a` method. That is why `Enumerable` knows first element for sure but they can not determine about its last element.

```
Enumerator#each
each_enum = (0..1).each
#=> #<Enumerator: 0..1:each> 
each_enum.to_a
#=> [0, 1]
```

Whereas

```
Enumerator#cycle
cycle_enum = (0..1).cycle
#=> #<Enumerator: 0..1:cycle> 
cycle_enum.to_a
```

keeps on pushing `next` element into array resulting in infinite loop.

See this [link(cycle)](http://ideone.com/qk5smw) and this [link(each)](http://ideone.com/ilrvtO) for few code execution to observe what I want to say.

Comment: "I do not agree with opinion that not all Enumerable has last element" - So, in this case, what is the last element of `cycle_enum`?